# Layout is broken when showing another panel in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm making wxPython frame. When the frame shows next panel, next panel's layout is broken despite using the same layout.
The code is below.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
    def _setup(self):
        # frame
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'widget', size=(self.Size.WIDTH, self.Size.HEIGHT))

        # panel1
        self.panel1 = self._get_panel()
        self.panel1.Show()

        # setting panel
        self.panel2 = self._get_panel()
        self.panel2.Hide()

        self.frame.Show()

    def _get_panel(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self.frame, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(0, self.Size.MENU), size=(self.Size.WIDTH, self.Size.HEIGHT - self.Size.MENU))

        layout = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        token_label = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'test')
        token_label.SetForegroundColour('#FFFFFF')
        layout.Add(token_label, flag=wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, border=self.Size.MARGIN)

        self._border(panel, layout)

        self.token_text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TE_LEFT)
        self.token_text.SetForegroundColour('#FFFFFF')
        self.token_text.SetBackgroundColour('#333333')
        layout.Add(self.token_text, flag=wx.GROW | wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=self.Size.MARGIN)

        panel.SetSizer(layout)

        self.btn_panel = wx.Panel(panel, 1, pos=(0, 380), size=(self.Size.WIDTH, 100))
        self.btn_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#5DFF3E')
        self.btn_panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.clicked)

    def clicked(self, event):
        self.panel1.Hide()
        self.panel2.Show()
```

And also these are images.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set sizer in setup.

```
def _setup(self):
        # frame
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'widget', size=(self.Size.WIDTH, self.Size.HEIGHT))

        # panel1
        self.panel1 = self._get_panel()
        self.panel1.Show()

        # setting panel
        self.panel2 = self._get_panel()
        self.panel2.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.frame.Show()
```

And when I switched the panel, I needed to call frame's layout function.

```
def clicked(self, event):
        self.panel1.Hide()
        self.panel2.Show()
        self.frame.Layout()
```

Thanks all.